# Proving a constant to the power of a constant is bigger than another constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the integral 
$ \space \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx $ and I found that it equals $ {1\over2} \arcsin x + x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

and when I placed in $ {1\over2} \arcsin{x} \space + \space x\sqrt{1-x^2} \space|_{-1}^{1} \space  $ I got $ - \pi\over2$ and wolfram alpha says it's $ \pi \over 2$, where did I go wrong?

(Way I solved it):

$$ ={1\over2} \cdot {\pi\over 2} + 0 - ({1\over2} \cdot {3\pi\over2} + 0)$$

$$ = {\pi\over 4}  \space - \space {3 \pi \over 4} = -{\pi\over 2}$$

Comment: This makes no sense, because $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ is a fixed number, whereas $ \frac12\arcsin{x}+x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ depends on $x$.

Comment: $\arcsin(-1)=-\pi/2$, not $3\pi/2$

Comment: $\arcsin(-1)=-\pi/2$.

Comment: oh Ok, thanks! Forgot that

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos then what might the integral be?

Comment: The integral is the area of a semicircle of radius $1$, so why bother doing this integral by integration?

Comment: @fdsaddsa The integral is equal to $\frac\pi2$, but I suspect that you did not understand my comment.

Comment: The range of $\arcsin$ is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ so, as observed above, you shouldn't get $3\pi/4$ in your computations.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman yup,  poyea pointed that out, thanks!

Comment: Right, which is why I specified "as observed **above**." Note, though, that this would change your computation to $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} - (\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{-\pi}{4}) = \frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as desired.

Comment: didn't notice that. Thanks for the great naswers everyone!

Comment: For the antiderivative, I get ${1\over2} \left(\arcsin x + x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$ rather than ${1\over2} \arcsin x + x\sqrt{1-x^2}. \qquad$

Comment: So a good answer should specify why one particular branch of the multiple-valued arcsine should be chosen. That cannot be just convention, since the value of the integral is one particular number and not another. $\qquad$

Comment: @fdsaddsa : It's perfectly legitimate to use $3\pi/2$ rather than $-\pi/2,$ PROVIDED you put the bounds in the correct order, with the one corresponding to $\sin=-1$ going where $-1$ was and the one corresponding to $\sin=1$ where then $+1$ was. See my answer below. $\qquad$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : Is there some way to find the area of a circle as a function of the radius that does not amount to integration in some sense?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I might've made a mistake somewhere, Ill look at my solution again, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2\,} \,dx $ by starting with the substitution $x=\sin\theta.$ As $x$ goes from $-1$ to $1,$ what does $\theta$ do?  It could go from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2,$ or from $3\pi/2$ to $\pi/2,$ but **not** from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2,$ since that would give you $\displaystyle \int^{-1}_1$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1.$

So you would need $\displaystyle \int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2},$ not $\displaystyle \int^{3\pi/2}_{\pi/2}$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't really sure why the 3pi / 2 was incorrect. Great explanation!

Comment: @fdsaddsa : I'm glad you liked it.